# Stumped Off A Wide Diamond Duck?

Tags: cricket, terminology, trivia

If you are stumped off a wide first delivery you face is it a diamond duck? Because although you have literally faced a ball it won't be recorded as a ball faced because of the wide (as evident [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ipl2009/engine/match/392217.html?batsman=2119;innings=2;view=commentary), Hayden faced 3 balls in the over he was dismissed but only 2 were counted cause he was stumped off a wide).

So if you are dismissed in this manner are you out for a diamond duck or not, as you will be out for 0 runs off 0 deliveries, but you will have also faced a ball? If not, does it have a special name too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just called diamond duck

This discussion provides much more clarity to this matter :

> Kieron Pollard was stumped off a wide from the first ball he received in the World Twenty20 match against England. Is this the first such "diamond duck" from a stumping rather than a run-out in international cricket? asked Tom from Australia
>
> Rather surprisingly, we can trace only one previous instance in
>   international cricket of a batsman being stumped first ball off a wide
>   (thus going down in the scorebook as having faced 0 balls). The man
>   who preceded Kieron Pollard in the Twenty20 international in
>   Providence last week was the Canadian fast bowler Henry Osinde, who
>   was stumped first ball by Niall O'Brien off an Alex Cusack wide while
>   playing Ireland in a one-day international during the World Cup
>   qualifying tournament in Benoni in April 2009. It's possible there are
>   further undetected instances - and several other people have been
>   stumped off wides at later stages of their innings in limited-overs
>   internationals.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/459191.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to Wikipedia, but with the allowance for regional definitional differences.

> A batsman who is dismissed without facing a ball (most usually run out from the non-striker's end, *but alternatively stumped* or run out *off a wide delivery*) is said to be out for a **diamond duck**, but in some regions that term has an alternative definition. [My italics.]

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_%28cricket%29)</sup>

Comment: It would be preferable if you give a reference _other_ than wikipedia...